# Optimum Sum-Difference

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given an array of integer values that represent a function (like a stair function, each value matches one unit of time, our purpose is to build another function (according to rule explained below) so that the difference between the original function's integral and our function's integral is maximum.

The rule is that the function that we build can be in 2 modes:

Mode A: our function values matches the given function.

Mode B : our function is static with the last value it had. The function cannot be in mode B for more than 3 consecutive units of time.

The initial point of both the functions is the same, i.e, they start at the same place.

Following is the naive recursive algorithm I implemented in Python:

```
def maximise(arr, sum, orig_sum, count, prev):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return abs(orig_sum - sum)
    same_path = maximise(arr[1:], sum+arr[0], orig_sum+arr[0], 0, prev)
    if count < 3:
        static_path = maximise(arr[1:], sum+prev, orig_sum+arr[0], count+1, prev)
        if static_path > same_path:
            return static_path
    return same_path

arr = [float(x) for x in input().split()]
print(maximise(arr[1:], arr[0], arr[0], 0, arr[0]))
```

For a given function, say `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the correct output is 6, because keeping constant at 1 gives an integral of 4, whereas the integral of the function `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is 10.

Comment: Do you want to maximize the absolute value of the difference? Or the sign is taken into account?

Comment: @algrid Absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to making this faster is to compute an array `f[t,b]` which is the best you can achieve for times up to `t`, given that you have finish with the use of exactly `b` time steps in Mode B.

From your constraints, b can only take values 0,1,2,3 so you only need to evaluate 4*n values of this array.

Each array value can be easily worked out from the values with smaller times, so  overall the complexity will be linear in the number of time steps.

### Pseudocode

```
def dp(arr):
    """Compute largest integral difference for increasing functions"""
    n=len(arr)
    DP=[[0]*4 for t in range(n+1)]
    for t,a in enumerate(arr):
        DP[t+1][0] = max(DP[t])
        for b in range(1,4):
            if t-b<0:
                continue
            DP[t+1][b] = DP[t][b-1] + ( a - arr[t-b] )
    return max(DP[n])

def dp2(arr):
    """Compute largest integral difference for arbitrary functions"""
    arr2=[-a for a in arr]
    return max(dp(arr),dp(arr2))
```

### Bug in original code

In the original code you have the line:

```
same_path = maximise(arr[1:], sum+arr[0], orig_sum+arr[0], 0, prev)
```

I think this should be:

```
same_path = maximise(arr[1:], sum+arr[0], orig_sum+arr[0], 0, arr[0])
```

Otherwise you are saying that mode B reuses the value from time 0, not the previous value.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like dynamic programming. I tried something similar but it didn't work out very well. Can you provide pseudocode, especially for the part of "working out" the array values?

Comment: Added some example pseudocode, this assumes the function is an increasing function and therefore you are trying to minimize the integral.

Comment: Why do we assume that?

Comment: I assumed that because you said in your question that it is a stair function which I interpreted as meaning it is an increasing function.  If this is not the case, add some examples where the function is not increasing and explain what answer should be produced.

Comment: For example, what should the answer be for [5,9,1]?  Your code returns 4, but if I choose to use mode B for the last value I would get a difference of 8.

Comment: Yes, so we want to choose the modes in such a way that we get the maximum possible difference.

Comment: I've added a function `dp2` that should work for arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thanks, but how would that work, can you please explain?

Comment: dp is trying to get the smallest integral possible, dp2 tries getting the largest integral and the smallest integral.  The largest difference must be given by one of these two.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing ... I mean our function cannot be in mode B for more than 3 *consecutive* units of time. Will the pseudo code still be valid for that constraint?

Comment: Yes, that is the constraint I have used.

Comment: If I print the final dynamic programming matrix, how do I deduce which indices have been a part of mode A and which have been part of mode B? Do we require separate backtracking for that?